# Vue2-Google-Maps Accessing gmapApi using beforeEnter() Route Guard

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vue2-google-maps

**Context:** I am trying to get place data via the place_id on the `beforeEnter()` route guard.  Essentially, I want the data to load when someone enters the url exactly `www.example.com/place/{place_id}`.  Currently, everything works directly when I use my autocomplete input and then enter the route but it does not work when I directly access the url from a fresh tab.  I believe the issue is because `google` has not been created yet.

**Question:** How can I access `PlacesService()` using the `beforeEnter()` route guard ?

**Error:** `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: google is not defined`

**Example Code:**
In one of my store modules:

```js
const module = {
  state: {
    selectedPlace: {}
  },
  actions: {
    fetchPlace ({ commit }, params) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let request = {
          placeId: params,
          fields: ['name', 'rating', 'formatted_phone_number', 'geometry', 'place_id', 'website', 'review', 'user_ratings_total', 'photo', 'vicinity', 'price_level']
        }
        let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'))
        service.getDetails(request, function (place, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            commit('SET_SELECTION', place)
            resolve()
          }
        })
      })
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_SELECTION: (state, selection) => {
      state.selectedPlace = selection
    }
  }
}

export default module
```

In my store.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import placeModule from './modules/place-module'
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'

Vue.use(Vuex)

// gmaps
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: process.env.VUE_APP_GMAP_KEY,
    libraries: 'geometry,drawing,places'
  }
})

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    placeModule: placeModule
  }
})
```

in my router:

```js
import store from '../state/store'

export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    components: {
      default: () => import('@/components/Home/HomeDefault.vue')
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/place/:id',
    name: 'PlaceProfile',
    components: {
      default: () => import('@/components/PlaceProfile/PlaceProfileDefault.vue')
    },
    beforeEnter (to, from, next) {
      store.dispatch('fetchPlace', to.params.id).then(() => {
        if (store.state.placeModule.selectedPlace === undefined) {
          next({ name: 'NotFound' })
        } else {
          next()
        }
      })
    }
  }
]
```

**What I've tried:**
- Changing `new google.maps.places.PlacesService` to `new window.new google.maps.places.PlacesService`
- Using `beforeRouteEnter()` rather than `beforeEnter()` as the navigation guard
- Changing `google.maps...` to `gmapApi.google.maps...` and `gmapApi.maps...`
- Screaming into the abyss 
- Questioning every decision I've ever made

**EDIT:** I've also tried the `this.$gmapApiPromiseLazy()` proposed in the wiki [here](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/wiki/vue-google-maps-FAQ#where-is-my-google)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin adds a mixin providing `this.$gmapApiPromiseLazy` to Vue instances (components) only but you're in luck... it also adds the same method to `Vue` statically

[Source code](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/blob/vue2/src/main.js#L63)

```js
Vue.mixin({
  created () {
    this.$gmapApiPromiseLazy = gmapApiPromiseLazy
  }
})

Vue.$gmapApiPromiseLazy = gmapApiPromiseLazy
```

So all you need to do in your store or router is use

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

// snip...

Vue.$gmapApiPromiseLazy().then(() => {
  let service = new google.maps.places....
})
```

Comment: You are a literal rockstar.  I was pulling my hair out for quite some time over this.  Just to make sure I understand the solution and can hopefully avoid situations in the future (total rookie here)...

This works because on the created instance they are defining       `this.$gmapApiPromiseLazy = gmapApiPromiseLazy`, right?  If this was not there I would be out of luck?

Comment: @JamesMurray you'd probably be able to work around it using the Google APIs but this certainly makes it easier